# Initializing Object and Assigning to Reference in Python

Tags: python, oop

I am a C++ and C# programmer and I am moving to Python because of school. I am faced with an error in a game I am making with object oriented principles. Heres the code:

```
class Entity(object):
  def __init__(self, name, hp):
    self.name = name
    self.hp = hp

  def attack(self, attack_name):
    pass

  def set_name(self, name):
    self.name = name

class Enemy(Entity):
  def __init__(self, name, hp):
    super(Enemy, self).__init__(name, hp)
    self.attacks = {} # creates a DICTINARY of attacks

  def add_attack(self, attack_name, attack_damage):
    self.attacks[attack_name] = attack_damage

  def attack(self, attack_name):
    if self.attacks[attack_name] == None:
      print("Attack not availible.")

    print(self.name + " is attacking with attack " + attack_name + " with " + self.attacks[attack_name])
    return self.attacks[attack_name]

  new_enemy = Enemy("Waddle Doo", 140)

  new_enemy.add_attack("Shoot Beam", 55)

  new_enemy.attack("Shoot Beam")
```

I created a class inherited from an **Entity** class called **Enemy**. I then tried to initiate an Enemy object but it gave me the error: **NameError: name 'Enemy' is not defined**. Why is this happening? Does it have to do something with how constructors work in Python? If you can help with this seemingly small problem, I thank you very much.

Comment: Your code's indentation is incorrect. Currently last 3 statements are part of the class.

Comment: Here's a tip: *everything in Python is an object*. Assignment is always *naming a reference*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's your indentation.

```
new_enemy = Enemy("Waddle Doo", 140)

new_enemy.add_attack("Shoot Beam", 55)

new_enemy.attack("Shoot Beam")
```

You are declaring the above in the scope of the Enemy class. Move them back to the level of the class Enemy(Entity): line